Proof of Theorem 3 (More Calculus) from 5.9.2 Evans PDE
From Evans PDE, the text presents the following Theorem 3 (More calculus):

Suppose $\mathbf{u} \in L^2\left(0, T ; H_0^1(U)\right)$, with $\mathbf{u}^{\prime} \in$ > $L^2\left(0, T ; H^{-1}(U)\right)$.

Then
$$
    \mathbf{u} \in C\left([0, T] ; L^2(U)\right)
    $$
(after possibly being redefined on a set of measure zero).
The mapping
$$
    t \mapsto\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2
    $$
is absolutely continuous, with
$$
    \frac{d}{d t}\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2=2\left\langle\mathbf{u}^{\prime}(t), \mathbf{u}(t)\right\rangle
    $$
for a.e. $0 \leq t \leq T$.
Furthermore, we have the estimate
\begin{equation}\label{eq:more_calculus_estimate}
        \max _{0 \leq t \leq T}\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)} \leq C\left(\|\mathbf{u}\|_{L^2\left(0, T ; H_0^1(U)\right)}+\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\right\|_{L^2\left(0, T ; H^{-1}(U)\right)}\right)
    \end{equation}
the constant $C$ depending only on $T$.


The proof of the third item says that

To obtain the equation, we integrate
\begin{equation}\label{eq:more_calculus_identify_u_v}
            \|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2=\|\mathbf{u}(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2+2 \int_s^t\left\langle\mathbf{u}^{\prime}(\tau), \mathbf{u}(\tau)\right\rangle d \tau
        \end{equation}
with respect to $s$, recall the inequality
$$\left|\left\langle\mathbf{u}^{\prime}, \mathbf{u}\right\rangle\right| \leq\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\right\|_{H^{-1}(U)}\|\mathbf{u}\|_{H_0^1(U)}$$
and make some simple estimates

I have two questions:

How to derive this inequality? I didn't recall this inequality at all.
I can't get to the right estimate, and I guess the problem is the second item on the right hand side. I tried

\begin{align*}
            \int_0^T\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2\ ds &=\int_0^T\|\mathbf{u}(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2\ ds+2\int_0^T  \int_s^t\left\langle\mathbf{u}^{\prime}(\tau), \mathbf{u}(\tau)\right\rangle d \tau ds \\
            T\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2 &\leq \int_0^T\|\mathbf{u}(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2\ ds+2\int_0^T \int_s^t\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}(\tau)\right\|_{H^{-1}(U)}\|\mathbf{u}(\tau)\|_{H_0^1(U)} d \tau ds\\
            \|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2 &\leq  \frac1T\int_0^T\|\mathbf{u}(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2\ ds + \frac2T \int_0^T (t-s)\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\right\|_{H^{-1}(U)}\|\mathbf{u}\|_{H_0^1(U)} ds\\
            \|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)}^2 &\leq \int_0^T \frac1T\|\mathbf{u}(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2\ ds +2t\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\right\|_{H^{-1}(U)}\|\mathbf{u}\|_{H_0^1(U)} -T\left\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\right\|_{H^{-1}(U)}\|\mathbf{u}\|_{H_0^1(U)}
        \end{align*}
and couldn't reach the final estimate (also, note that my calculation above, especially from the second line to the third line, could be terribly wrong).
Note: the desired estimate is
$$
            \max _{0 \leq t \leq T}\|\mathbf{u}(t)\|_{L^2(U)} \leq C\left(\left(\int_0^T \|\mathbf{u}(t)\|^2\ dt\right)^{1/2}+\left(\int_0^T \|\mathbf{u}'(t)\|^2\ dt\right)^{1/2}\right)
$$

maybe you only miss the inequalities $ab \le \frac12(a^2+b^2)$ and $\sqrt{ a^2+b^2} \le a+b$ for $a,b\ge0$.

The inequality
$$
|\langle u',u\rangle| \le \|u'\|_{H^{-1}} \|u\|_{H^1}
$$
follows from the construction of $H^{-1}$ as the dual space of $H^1_0$. That space is discussed in section 5.9.1, right before the section, where this result appears.
For the second question:
$$
\int_s^t \langle u',u\rangle d\tau \le \int_s^t \|u'\|_{H^{-1}} \|u\|_{H^1} d\tau\le \int_0^T \|u'\|_{H^{-1}} \|u\|_{H^1} d\tau
\le \int_0^T \frac12\|u'\|_{H^{-1}}^2 + \frac12 \|u\|_{H^1}^2 d\tau.
$$
Now this term is independent of $s,t$. Then integrate wrt $s$, and take the supremum wrt $t$.
